# ActionBarSherlock icon overflow

Tags: android, image, actionbarsherlock

Is it possible to make the ABS icon overflow ABS height?

In html/css I would set an absolute postion on the image or a negative margin to achieve this. How can it be made in Android and espacially in ABS?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom layout for actionbar. Search for that you should be easily able to implement what you want!

Comment: Creating a custom layout shouldn't be a problem. But I dont't see how I could make an element overflow this layout.